# Como salvar imagens de um ImageView android em um banco de dados Mysql usando um web service rest em java

Tags: android, mysql, imageview

Tenho um aplicativo android com um ImageView que recebe uma imagem do dispositivo, e preciso salvá-la em um banco de dados mysql atraves de um web service Java como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia transformar a sua imagem em um array de bytes e transferir para o web service e salvar no banco de dados como um binário.